# WCF throwing before sending response to client

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service where IGameServices contains:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGameServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    DtoReturnedMessage<DtoGame> GetGame(Guid gameId);
}
```

AdminServices contains:

```
public class AdminService : IGameServices
{
    private readonly BoGame _boGame = new BoGame();

    public DtoReturnedMessage<DtoGame> GetGame(Guid gameId)
    {
        return _boGame.Get(gameId);
    }
}
```

I have that BoGame, which is a class with business logics.

My config is:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGameServices" sendTimeout="00:05:00" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:50380/Services/Implementations/AdminService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGameServices"
            contract="IGameServices" name="BasicHttpBinding_IGameServices" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I debug it step-by-step, all the business logics works properly, and throws the exception below when the response should be sent to the client.

```
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:50380/Services/Implementations/AdminService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IGameServices.GetGame(Guid gameId)
   at GameServicesClient.GetGame(Guid gameId)

Inner Exception:
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Inner Exception:
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

Inner Exception:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

It is weird because I have a method to save some data into the DB, in the same IGameServices, which saves normally and returns the success message as expected.

Does any one know what that can be?

Comment: Who is consuming this service?  The error message is telling you that the remote client didn't wait for the response.  There isn't a necessarily a code problem on your end, its a patience problem on the other end.

Comment: Did you already turn on tracing to have more detailed Logs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @khlr , Yes. I solved the problem. The error was too generic, actually. The issue was with build versions of postsharp not matching. I found out by trying to open the services directly on the browser. I removed Postsharp in that project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The error was too generic, actually. The issue was with build versions of Postsharp not matching.

I found it out by trying to open the services directly on the browser. I removed Postsharp in that project and BANG.